# how to alter a mysql innodb partition to use another key?

Tags: mysql, innodb, partitioning

I have a table with 5 hash(key_1) partitions. I want to change that, so it instead has 5 hash(key_2) partitions, but without losing data.

How do I do this? I have searched but its hard to find confirmation that I dont lose data by deleting partitions.

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by partitioning?  (In my opinion, `BY HASH` is totally useless.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting, truncating, or dropping partitions will definitely lose data. You can change partitioning this with `ALTER TABLE`, for example `ALTER TABLE t PARTITION BY HASH (key_2) PARTITIONS 5`. This won't lose data, but (at least with InnoDB), the table will be locked for writes and rebuilt with the new partitioning.